# Using `continue` as a break statement

Tags: python, structure, break, readability, continue

I know a lot of people debate on `break` vs. `if condition: quit == True` in `while` and `until` loops.  I've heard a common opinion of `break` is that it isn't verbose and it can lead to terrible code structure.  Though I was working on a project for CS110, and I needed to make a menu, that would cycle though until a user entered `'Q'`, and would add commands onto a list until `'X'` was inputted, then it would execute those commands.  If the command started with `'X'`, you can do other stuff, like play a song, but I didn't want that to be obvious to the user.  This is my code in Python

```
usrCommands = []

def menu():
    global usrCommands

    # Take user input
    quit = False
    while not quit :
        print("Please enter a command for the Finch :")
        print("\tW - Move Forward")
        print("\tS - Move Backward")
        print("\tA - Turn Left")
        print("\tD - Turn Right")
        print("\tX - Execute Commands")
        print("\tQ - Quit")
        usrIn = input("> ").upper()
        print()

        # Parse for valid input
        contains = False
        for letter in 'WSADQ' :
            if usrIn.find(letter) != -1:
                contains = True
        # execute if command is invalid unless the command starts with 'X'
        if not( (contains and len(usrIn) == 1) or (usrIn.find('X') == 0) ):
            displayInvalid()
            continue
        if usrIn == 'Q' :
            quit = True
            continue

        if usrIn != 'X':
            usrCommands.append(usrIn)
        print(usrCommands)
```

My question is in the

```
if usrIn == 'Q' :
    quit = True
    continue
```

block.  Here I've got the same syntax as an `if` terminating a `while` loop the normal way, but instead of including it at the end, I have the same effect as using a break statement.  However, here you can easily see that `quit` is now equal to `True`.  Is this an effective medium between `break` and the standard way of doing this, for lack of better words?  Are there any foreseeable problems with this in other projects?

Comment: It is semantically equivalent to `break`, while adding more code: I'd say it's worse. People who are okay with `break` will prefer `break`; people who don't like `break` don't like it because of a jump, and will have the same problem with `continue`. However, this is an opinion question, and could easily end up being closed for that reason.

Comment: @Amadan, if it does get closed, oh well.  It's not an important issue, just something I got curious about

Comment: To me, in this situation, break seems like a more explicit instruction, and therefore the more logical choice. I don't think there is anything confusing about break. It merely would end the loop. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has essentially a very similar effect to `break`, in terms of semantics. You are aborting the loop early using a keyword. So for the same reason you wouldn’t use `break`, you wouldn’t use `continue` there.

That being said, your structure does complicate things: First, it introduces an additional loop condition variable that has no other responsibility other than providing a work-around for `break`. It does make the code more complicated though (e.g. you don’t immediately see that `quit` is *only* changed where the `continue` happens). Second, it requires reevaluation of the loop condition although you already know its result. So if we were to look at the byte code, instead of jumping to the end of the loop (as with `break`), we jump to the start, recheck the condition and *then* jump to the end.

So, just to make it easier, I would absolutely use `break` there. Note though that the common reasoning for not using `break` is not the keyword itself but the fact that it introduces an additional exit from your loop (just like using `returns` early in functions); and you are not changing that at all with using `continue` there. So either use `break`, or don’t interrupt the loop at all.

Comment: So would you suggest I use `while True:` and just explicitly call break?  I know this is a very opinionated question but, would that be considered an appropriate use for `break` in this context?

Comment: I’m not a purist that only allows a single exit point, so yes, I personally prefer a simple `break` to end the loop early. I believe it conveys the intent better and allows to simplify the overall structure.